# Undefined global variable when using QuestaSim

Tags: embedded, verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I have a variable defined in foo_const.v which is defined like this in foo_const.v:

```
localparam NUM_BITS = 32;
```

Then I have another file foo_const_slice.v which does this:

```
localparam SLICE_ADDR_BITS = NUM_BITS;
```

This compiles fine with the vcs command:

`vcs -sverilog foo_const.v foo_const_slice.v`

But when I try to use QuestaSim:

`vlog -work work -sv foo_const.v foo_const_slice.v`

I get the following error message:

`** Error: foo_const_slice.v(46): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'NUM_BITS'.`

Comment: Is `NUM_BITS` defined in any scope? I mean, is it in a module or a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default, each file that vlog compiles goes into a separate compilation unit, just like C/C++ and many other languages. By default, vcs concatenates all files together into a single compilation unit.

Although there is a way to change the default (you can look it up in the user manual), the proper way to code this is to put your parameters in a package, and import the package where needed.

Dave

Comment: adding -mfcu fixed it :) tnx for the tips :)